# Win32 C++ Alphablend a Bitmap Partially Transparent

Tags: c++, winapi, alphablending

I've googled, seen examples, other questions here, MSDN and Downloaded Example code. I cannot figure out what is wrong with this.

```
// setting up the memory DC and selecting in the bitmap
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap.hbmLogo);

// setting up the blend function
BLENDFUNCTION bStruct; 
bStruct.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
bStruct.BlendFlags = 0;
bStruct.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
bStruct.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

// try
BOOL check = AlphaBlend(buffer.getBufferDC(), 0, 0, bitmap.bmLogo.bmWidth, bitmap.bmLogo.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, bitmap.bmLogo.bmWidth, bitmap.bmLogo.bmHeight, bStruct);
if (check == FALSE) MessageBox(0,0,0,0);

// this is how I load the bitmap, it is a resource. 
bitmap.hbmLogo = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LOGO_0));
if (bitmap.hbmLogo == NULL) { MessageBox(NULL, "Could not read the logo bitmap.", "Error", MB_OK); return false; }
GetObject(bitmap.hbmLogo, sizeof(bitmap.bmLogo), &bitmap.bmLogo);
```

I use the message box to quickly check the result. Check always returns TRUE. The bitmap and its dimensions are correct.

I've tried it over different background colors, alpha values, and still nothing, replacing that with BitBlt or TransparentBitBlt, no problem, the logo displays. All my attempts with the AlphaBlend function has resulted in no change. The logo does not appear, even for a second, on the screen.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

[image: Here is the bitmap.]

Comment: you're gonna give us a little more details than that.  do you have the bitmap selected to the hdcmem?  what are the values in bstruct?   etc.  what do you expect to see?  what do you actually see?

Comment: My mistake, updating now.

Comment: you're gonna have to give the piece of code that creates the bitmap... the format of the bitmap matters.

Comment: Also, `DeleteDC` on a DC you get back from `GetDC` isn't a good idea (particularly when you also call `ReleaseDC` on the same thing two lines later).

Comment: Where does the HDC come from with buffer.getBufferDC()?

Comment: interesting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183533(v=vs.85).aspx.  An application must not delete a DC whose handle was obtained by calling the GetDC function. Instead, it must call the ReleaseDC function to free the DC..  Good call.  while probably not the issue at hand, it may cause funky problems in the future.

Comment: My bad, I left out a ton of info. The HDC in getBufferDC() is setup in a double buffer class (I use it with everything requiring a buffer)

Comment: I fixed the DeleteDC/ ReleaseDC, code updated.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `BitBlt` in place of the `AlphaBlend` to see if the problem is there or somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, I tried BitBlt, and TransparentBlt, both work no problem (including the proper transparency on the white.)

Comment: what is the format of the bitmap in resource?  rgb 888? rgba 8888?  i think that alphablend requires an alpha channel.  if you don't have a, it doesn't work (and may not tell you so).  been awhile since i used it, so don't quote me on this, but worth a shot.

Comment: yup: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183393(v=vs.85).aspx.  the documentation confirms - When the AlphaFormat member is AC_SRC_ALPHA, the source bitmap must be 32 bpp. If it is not, the AlphaBlend function will fail.  if you want to use alpha, you need to have alpha.

Comment: In addition, if you do have a 32-bit bitmap and all of your alpha bytes are 0, your bitmap is transparent.

Comment: `LoadBitmap` will not preserve the alpha channel of the source image, so it probably will be 0.

Comment: can probably save it as a binary resource and parse it yourself... that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Seems that the problem is with the bitmap. I tried saving various settings in photoshop and paint. Nothing. Strange thing though, the test example uses a 8 bit bitmap. It was compiled with visual studio so I was unable to test any of my images against something that does work.

I think I am going to check out GDI+. I googled and looked at MSDN, I couldn't find much info on it. Anyone know where I can find GDI+ examples or tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution after looking closer at an example.

I set the BLENDFUNCTION as a global, and in the WM_CREATE message I used:

```
    m_bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    m_bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    m_bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 100; // any 0 to 255
    m_bf.AlphaFormat = 0;
    LoadBitmapsFromResource();
```

and it is now working.